# Unable to successfully use axios with React Native to make a request (IOS)

Tags: django, react-native, axios

I'm unable to make a successful request with Axios. I have tested with Postman to make sure the server is correct and it works without a problem there.

The error I'm getting is

```
Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

The way I'm making my call to the backend is

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    axios.get(`https://127.0.0.1:8080/tasks/`).then((res) => {}).catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

Am I doing something wrong in regards to axios? I don't even hit the endpoint since my `print("hit")`never gets logged through the phone (works with postman though)

Thank you for all the help

When using Fetch

```
const onSubmit = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { Content_Type: 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id, title, description, date: moment.utc(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') })
        };

        fetch(`http://10.0.0.150:8080/tasks/update_task`, requestOptions)
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('the task is: ', task);
                console.log('succeeded');
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    };
```

Comment: I have the exact same error in IOS. Did you ever figure out how to make it work?

Comment: @ponder275 Hello. I did but a temporary solution. I have the server running as http://0.0.0.0:8080/ which allows any request to be accepted from my understanding. I also stopped using axios and instead am using fetch. I"ll add an example to the bottom of the question on top. Hope it helps even if temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case I had to change localhost in the url I was getting to the actual IP address.

Comment: @ponder275 Thanks for sharing that one. I did see that as another option. Currently did go that route